# System.TypeLoadException.: 'Could not load type "" from assembly 'Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,

Tags: c#, unhandled-exception

I'm currently having this issue during the debug of my code.
It continues giving me this

> System.TypeLoadException 'Could not load type "" from assembly
> 'Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral.

What is the most interesting is the fact that, if I run the code on a different laptop, it runs withouth any problem.
Any reccomandation? Maybe changing some VS settings?
Thanks,
Arianna

I've tried to change the assembly name or follow a lot of suggestions I found online but nothing did work for me.

Comment: Have you installed the sdk?

Comment: Yes it is installed